# How to find gunicorn path in Ubuntu using terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, gunicorn

I have installed gunicorn in my Ubuntu virtual machine using `sudo apt-get install gunicorn`. How can I find the installed location of gunicorn?

Comment: Have you tried `which gunicorn` in a shell?

Comment: yes i tried. but that location does not exists.("/home/jkcsadmin/.local/bin/gunicorn
")

Comment: Have you accidentally run the `which` command outside of the virtual machine? Or run it inside, but looked up the path outside? If `which` finds the command there, then it is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you checked it is not available in location `/home/jkcsadmin/.local/bin/gunicorn` ? Try `/home/jkcsadmin/.local/bin/gunicorn -h` and see whether it shows the help.

Normally it is located at your bin folder `/usr/bin/gunicorn`. Try `/usr/bin/gunicorn -h`

Answer (score 19):

Sorry for posting late. Might still be helpful for others.

Try this-

```
whereis gunicorn
```

Comment: you are the best